# The specified child already has a parent you must call removeview

Tags: android

I have removed all the views then added a view still am getting this error.

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(isHierarchical){

                    IndexTableActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    final ExpandableListView expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.laptop_list);

                    booksLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.booksLV);
                    System.out.println("THE NUMBERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR "+expListView);
                    btn2.setText("L");
                    isHierarchical=false;
                        createGroupList();
                        createCollection();


                        final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                                IndexTableActivity.this, groupList, laptopCollection);

                        IndexTableActivity.this. setContentView(R.layout.main);

                        LinearLayout listView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) listView.getParent();
                        if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                            parentViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();;
                            parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();

                        }
                        listView.removeAllViews();

                        listView.addView(expListView);// am getting error here 
                        expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
                }else{
                    btn2.setText("H");

                    isHierarchical=true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me to find out why am getting this error? and how to resolve it.

The error log

[image]
Thank you

Comment: Your expListView has already a parent, because it is in the activity_main i assume... So the problem is with the expListView not with the listview

Comment: @Alex It is present in activity_main but after that i have changed the    content view to "main"  IndexTableActivity.this. setContentView(R.layout.main); Then i tried to add the expListView  to the main (Actually expListView  belongs to activity_main )

Comment: @Amith Please post some more code with the logcat error.

Comment: @GrIsHu have updated the question please have a look.

Comment: @Alex Its throwing error because you have already inflated the `activity_main` layout before the `main` layout. And you are trying to remove the views of `main` layout. First you need to remove the views of `activity_main` layout then only you can remove views of child layout.

Answer (score 0):

From your code its bit complicated to understand what you are trying to achieve. Because first your are adding the layout then after directly removing it and again adding the views into the already removed layout. Its strange.

Remove `listView.removeAllViews();` because you already removed the view and then after you are trying to add the another view into it. Which is wrong way.

Remove the below code:

```
         if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                        parentViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();;
                        parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();

                    }
      listView.removeAllViews();
```

Just add the view into the layout first.

```
     listView.addView(expListView);// am getting error here 
     expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
```

Comment: I have a page, that includes a search field a button and a list. On the button click i have to change the normal list view to expandable list view this is what i exactly trying to do

Comment: @GrlsHu So am removing the existing list view and adding the new one.